# Method to add timestamp to excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sending out a weekly completion sign-off for all of our weekly training to my co-workers.

I want it to provide a timestamp to in `K2` whenever a value is populated with either true or false in either `h2`, `i2` or `l2` and so on... I'm sure I can figure out how to get it to apply to the other cells but I need help getting started.

I've tried using `NOW()` but every time you make a change or open the workbook it updates and I need this to be auto-populated once for verification purposes.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: a bit of vba to copy / paste value when the other cell has an acceptable value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will need to be done in VBA, because as you've stated, the `Now()` worksheet function will automatically update when the worksheet is recalculated.

You can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event to do this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim colRng As Range
    Set colRng = Union(Me.Columns("H"), Me.Columns("I"), Me.Columns("L"))

    If Not Intersect(Target, colRng) Is Nothing and (target.value = True or _
                target.Value = false) Then
        Me.Cells(Target.Row, "K").Value = Now
    End If

End Sub
```

At this point, anytime you update a cell in columns `H`, `I`, or `L`, the corresponding row in column `K` will now have your timestamp.

---

If you are not familiar with VBA, then the easiest way for you to do this is to **Right-Click** the sheet tab at the bottom of excel, then click **View Code**. Once the new window opens up, you will need to paste the above code block into the VBE. Then you can simply close this window and proceed to the highlighted portion below.

> You will need to resave this as a new workbook format. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> while you have the worksheet active, and then in the **Save as type** drop-down, select `Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm)`.

Comment: Glad to assist!